# Best way to get current user purchased products

Tags: 7, commerce, database

I need to get purchased products by the current user ([Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)).

I use this function to reach there :

```
function mymodule_user_purchased_products() {
    global $user;
    $query = db_select('commerce_order', 'corder');
    $query->join('commerce_line_item', 'li', 'corder.order_id = li.order_id');
    $query->join('field_data_commerce_product', 'prod', 'li.line_item_id = prod.entity_id');
    $query->condition('corder.uid', $user->uid, '=')
          ->condition('corder.status', 'completed', '=')
          ->fields('prod', array('commerce_product_product_id'));
    $result = $query->execute();
}
```

But I think I forget certain things, and this solution isn't optimal.

Is it the recommended way?

Comment: What's not optimal about it?

Comment: It is not a "heavy" solution? In particular in case the user would have bought numerous products? There are not ways to optimize it? If she is optimal, it's perfect ;)

Comment: Cache the results if you need or write hooks to store it in a custom table if you need to do more with the data, but if it works, then use what you have.

Answer (score 0):

One one thing that I can think of to change. Make sure you only get a single result.

```
$query = db_select('commerce_order', 'corder');
$query->join('commerce_line_item', 'li', 'corder.order_id = li.order_id');
$query->join('field_data_commerce_product', 'prod', 'li.line_item_id = prod.entity_id');
$query->condition('corder.uid', $user->uid, '=')
      ->condition('corder.status', 'completed', '=')
      ->addExpression('DISTINCT prod.commerce_product_product_id', 'product_id');
```

Using this line:

```
->addExpression('DISTINCT prod.commerce_product_product_id', 'product_id');
```

instead of:

```
->fields('prod', array('commerce_product_product_id'));
```

will insure that you only get one product_id per row in your result. By using the `DISTINCT` SQL Keyword, it will only allow distinct values to be returned.

Comment: Thanks nvahalik, I'm going to change this line. One thing: from what moment does it become necessary to create a custom table? Approximately, from how many products on the site for example?